# post method is not working in laravel 8 with react native for android

Tags: php, android, laravel, react-native

i am new in laravel and i am using laravel backend with react native for android and trying to send data from react native to laravel using post method but it is not working.
this is Controller for Posts.

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function store(Request $request) {
       $post =  Post::create([
       'title' => $request->title,
       'description' => $request->description,
       ]);
       $post->save();
     return response()->json([
      'message' => 'stored post sucessfully',   
     ],201);
    }
}
```

this is api in api.php for adding post

```
Route::post('savePost', [PostController::class, 'store']);
```

i am using this api in frontend like this

```
const data = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'First Post',
      description: 'this is my first post',
    }),
  };

const post = async () => {
 await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/savePost', data)
      .then(res => console.log('res', res.json()))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

it is returning this response

```
 {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "7cef9594-5824-40a5-8186-38f04f5a2f00", "offset": 0, "size": 14036}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "7cef9594-5824-40a5-8186-38f04f5a2f00", "offset": 0, "size": 14036}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"access-control-allow-origin": "*", "cache-control": "no-cache, private", "connection": "close", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Thu, 16 Dec 2021 15:34:44 GMT, Thu, 16 Dec 2021 15:34:44 GMT", "host": "10.0.2.2:8000", "x-powered-by": "PHP/7.4.3", "x-ratelimit-limit": "60", "x-ratelimit-remaining": "59"}}, "ok": false, "status": 500, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/savePost"}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Looks like you have an HTTP 500 error: `"status": 500,`; you'll need to check your Logs (`storage/framework/logs/laravel.log` or `laravel-{date}.log`) to see the exact error message.

Comment: Can you show us as well model class. 

p.s. when you are using `create` method, you don't need to use `save()`, it saves itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to do mass assignment in post model. It should be like this.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```